# Сравнительный оборот с КАК ОТ

Tags: сравнительный-оборот

Опять не могу определиться со сравнительным оборотом! Здесь нужны запятые в обоих случаях или это *приравнивание, отождествление* и запятых не нужно?

В эру всемирной электронной связи руководители и управляющие компаний оградили себя защитой от потока сторонней оживляющей информации как от «спама», выплескивая ее золотые крупицы, а не выискивая их, и не выращивают изобретателей, а ограждаются от них как от охотников за деньгами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, это отождествление, запятые не нужны, значения оборотов " в качестве, считая, рассматривая".